# Issues in loading and saving Customer addresses where customer is linked to many addresses (200+)

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-address, save

My customer has 200+ addresses, the page takes a long time to respond(this is one issue),and other is when I try to save some changes,I am getting error as shown in pic.If customer has few addresses, it is (loading, saving) is working fine.I am unable to trace any thing about **long time to respond** and issue on **Save** for large no of addresses, any help, guide will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this issue as well previously, although not directly related the same issue was occuring on a large number of customer records, some had 100+ addresses in their address book.

- [Customized Customer Grid causing MySQL table scans and filesorts aka slow performance](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270/customized-customer-grid-causing-mysql-table-scans-and-filesorts-aka-slow-perfor)

The best advice unfortunately is to create an indexed (flat table) of your own of the customer's address book.  This would most likely optimize and/or speed up the slow loading times.  If it's an edge case of only very few customers then you'd most likely be better off taking the DB optimization approach and/or bumping up DB server memory to hold all of the results in cache.

- http://aionhill.com/magento-fast-indexing-implementation
- http://www.mexbs.com/creating-custom-magento-index/

The quick win would also be to optimize your `my.cnf` settings of MySQL to try and cache as much as possible for the lookup of the request(s) using mysqltuner.pl or mysqlprimer.pl scripts and tweak the innodb settings specifically. NOTE: These are merely for advice and as a guide, always best to measure performance when changing settings.

- [Full Page Cache on CE 1.8 - An FPC Magento Module? Varnish? Both?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13957/full-page-cache-on-ce-1-8-an-fpc-magento-module-varnish-both/13992#13992)

As for the frontend issue, I believe a pagination system of some type would need to be implemented to chop the number of address books to display at a time would ultimately be the best way to not overload the client browser with 100s of MB of data for javascript to try and parse to send to the backend to save.

Again, if this is an edge case however, perhaps limiting the collection and or digging out the specific ID from the database itself to return if needing to edit from the admin specifically.  If the issue is also on the frontend to the customer then paginating the results would be best.

There is also this but looks to be from 1.5CE, but may possibly help some as well:

- http://www.createhosting.co.nz/support/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=55